# Symfony2 format view for EntityType

Tags: symfony

I have field EntityType into form builder:

```
$builder->add('parent', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AdBundle:AdLocation',
                'choice_label' => 'title',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('l')
                        ->where('l.visible = :visible')
                        ->setParameter('visible', true);
                }
            ))
```

Field 'parent' contains list of locations: country, city, district(like categories). I want to struct data view like:

- Country
- - City
- - - District
- - - District
- - City
- - - District
      ...
- - City

Where formatting logic best to store? Form Type or controller or service?

Comment: database is best to store, no sorry question is unclear for me, how is your data malstructured? what problem do you face ?

Comment: I have entity AdLocation, with One-To-Many, Self-referencing relation. And I want to view this data in hierarchy format: Top - Country, City in Country, District in city, like categories. Sorry for my english.